# php-mysql installed but not showing in phpinfo

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I just upgraded my phpversion from php 7.1 to 7.3. Unfortunately I can't seem to get mysql working.
I'm on a centos 7 box using yum package manager.
These are my installed php packages. I've rebooted and tried uninstalling, reinstalling the mysql extension and it still won't show up in the phpinfo. The only mention of mysql is in the credits section.

```
php73.x86_64                                                                 2.0-1.el7.remi                                                        @remi-safe
php73-common.x86_64                                                          7.3.28-1.el7.ius                                                      @ius
php73-json.x86_64                                                            7.3.28-1.el7.ius                                                      @ius
php73-mbstring.x86_64                                                        7.3.28-1.el7.ius                                                      @ius
php73-pdo.x86_64                                                             7.3.28-1.el7.ius                                                      @ius
php73-pdo-dblib.x86_64                                                       7.3.28-1.el7.ius                                                      @ius
php73-php-cli.x86_64                                                         7.3.28-1.el7.remi                                                     @remi-safe
php73-php-common.x86_64                                                      7.3.28-1.el7.remi                                                     @remi-safe
php73-php-json.x86_64                                                        7.3.28-1.el7.remi                                                     @remi-safe
php73-php-mysqlnd.x86_64                                                     7.3.28-1.el7.remi                                                     @remi-safe
php73-php-pdo.x86_64                                                         7.3.28-1.el7.remi                                                     @remi-safe
php73-php-pear.noarch                                                        1:1.10.12-7.el7.remi                                                  @remi-safe
php73-php-pecl-mcrypt.x86_64                                                 1.0.4-1.el7.remi                                                      @remi-safe
php73-php-pecl-mysql.x86_64                                                  1.0.0-0.20.20180226.647c933.el7.remi                                  @remi-safe
php73-php-pecl-xdebug3.x86_64                                                3.0.4-1.el7.remi                                                      @remi-safe
php73-php-process.x86_64                                                     7.3.28-1.el7.remi                                                     @remi-safe
php73-php-soap.x86_64                                                        7.3.28-1.el7.remi                                                     @remi-safe
php73-php-xml.x86_64                                                         7.3.28-1.el7.remi                                                     @remi-safe
php73-runtime.x86_64                                                         2.0-1.el7.remi                                                        @remi-safe
```

Comment: Have you restart the FPM service ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>  php73-php-common.x86_64  7.3.28-1.el7.remi   @remi-safe
>  php73-common.x86_64      7.3.28-1.el7.ius    @ius
> ```

You are mixing 2 PHP stacks from 2 different providers, IUS and Remi.

You should only use one.

For **remi** repository, I recommend you follow the [Wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/) instructions

Notice: I don't see any mod_php or fpm package in your list...

> Then add extension=yourExtension.so to php.ini,

Never do this, with RPM, each package provides the proper configuration file for its extension(s). After installation you need to restart the httpd or php-fpm service.

Comment: Ended up uninstalling everything and reinstalling following the wizard to make sure I wasn't mixing repos and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using php-fpm, you can use `php-fpm -i | grep php.ini` to find the loaded configuration file.

If using php-cli, `php -i | grep php.ini`, and so on.

> On some occasions, php-fpm and php-cli aren't using the same php.ini.
>
> php -i -> php-cli
>
> php-fpm -i -> php-fpm

Then add `extension=yourExtension.so` to php.ini, and restart your php-fpm, using `php-fpm -m | grep yourExtension` to check if the extension is loaded, it means work if printed you extension name.

If there's not, then, you need to find the extension_dir of php : `php-fpm -i | grep extension_dir`, and check if there is yourExtension.so file, if there's not, it means your extension installed to a wrong place, you need make a soft link or simply cp yourExtension.so to that place.

If you're using multi-version php, you need check which php you are using.